# Getting WebDriverSampler: Cannot cast org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebElement to org.openqa.selenium.By error

Tags: selenium, jmeter

When I try running my jmeter webdriver sampler with the below code I am getting the error message as shown below.

```
 var selenium = JavaImporter(org.openqa.selenium)
 var time = JavaImporter(java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit)
 WDS.browser.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(30, time.TimeUnit.SECONDS)
 WDS.sampleResult.sampleStart()

 WDS.log.info("Enter email batch details");
 var batchNameText = WDS.browser.findElement(selenium.By.xpath("//div[contains(@data-testid,\"batchNameTextField\")]//input"))
    wait.until(EC.presenceOfElementLocated(batchNameText));
    batchNameText.click();
    batchNameText.clear();
    batchNameText.sendKeys("test");
    batchNameText.SendKeys(selenium.Keys.TAB);

 WDS.sampleResult.sampleEnd()
```

Error in log file shows as

> java.lang.ClassCastException: Cannot cast
> org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebElement to org.openqa.selenium.By
> at java.lang.invoke.MethodHandleImpl.newClassCastException(Unknown
> Source) at java.lang.invoke.MethodHandleImpl.castReference(Unknown
> Source) at jdk.nashorn.internal.scripts.Script$5$^eval_.:program(
> :39) at
> jdk.nashorn.internal.runtime.ScriptFunctionData.invoke(ScriptFunctionData.java:637)
> at
> jdk.nashorn.internal.runtime.ScriptFunction.invoke(ScriptFunction.java:494)
> at
> jdk.nashorn.internal.runtime.ScriptRuntime.apply(ScriptRuntime.java:393)
> at
> jdk.nashorn.api.scripting.NashornScriptEngine.evalImpl(NashornScriptEngine.java:449)
> at
> jdk.nashorn.api.scripting.NashornScriptEngine.evalImpl(NashornScriptEngine.java:406)
> at
> jdk.nashorn.api.scripting.NashornScriptEngine.evalImpl(NashornScriptEngine.java:402)
> at
> jdk.nashorn.api.scripting.NashornScriptEngine.eval(NashornScriptEngine.java:155)
> at javax.script.AbstractScriptEngine.eval(Unknown Source) at
> com.googlecode.jmeter.plugins.webdriver.sampler.WebDriverSampler.sample(WebDriverSampler.java:86)
> at
> org.apache.jmeter.threads.JMeterThread.doSampling(JMeterThread.java:638)
> at
> org.apache.jmeter.threads.JMeterThread.executeSamplePackage(JMeterThread.java:558)
> at
> org.apache.jmeter.threads.JMeterThread.processSampler(JMeterThread.java:489)
> at org.apache.jmeter.threads.JMeterThread.run(JMeterThread.java:256)
> at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)

Not sure whats the issue here. Its same as getting webelement and assigning it to a variable as what I guess.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: presenceOfElementLocated is expecting a by locator... you're giving it a webelement.  (btw, you shouldn't mix implicit and explicit waits.)  That EC will return the webelement if found, so you can combine those lines... var batchNameText =  wait.until(EC...

Comment: Thanks @pcalkins, Initially I was using By locator and while changing for other lines I accidentally changed to this wait statement. Also I changed as you mentioned to combine my wait with the findElement

Answer (score 1):

Looking at `presenceOfElementLocated​` function [JavaDoc](https://www.selenium.dev/selenium/docs/api/java/org/openqa/selenium/support/ui/ExpectedConditions.html#presenceOfElementLocated(org.openqa.selenium.By)) it expects [By](https://www.selenium.dev/selenium/docs/api/java/org/openqa/selenium/By.html) class instance and you're passing a [WebElement](https://www.selenium.dev/selenium/docs/api/java/org/openqa/selenium/WebElement.html) to it that's why your code fails.

So my expectation is that you need to change it to something like:

```
wait.until(EC.presenceOfElementLocated(selenium.By.xpath("//div[contains(@data-testid,\"batchNameTextField\")]//input"))
```

Going forward please include the full code because it's not very clear what is `EC` as it isn't declared anywhere.

More information on WebDriver Sampler: [The WebDriver Sampler: Your Top 10 Questions Answered](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/webdriver-sampler-your-top-ten-questions-answered)